# I am thinking of getting myself a dog, is it a good idea?

Tags: dogs, vocalizations, breeds

I am thinking of getting a dog. I want to learn about some breeds of which dogs won't bark so much. Does anybody know about any non-barking breeds?

Answer (score 5):

There are some breeds that have the tendency to bark a lot - mostly guarding and herding breeds, but also many smaller breeds categorized as "toy breeds".

**Dog breeds that bark a lot** include: Beagle, Chihuahua, Pomeranian, Siberian Husky, Yorkshire Terrier, West Highland White Terrier (and most other terriers), Border Collie, German Shepherd, Australian Shepherd, Corgie, Boxer, Miniature Schnauzer.

**Dog breeds that don't bark so much** include: Basenji (the only dog breed that is physically unable to bark), Bernese Mountain Dog, Cavalier King Charles Spaniel, Greyhound, Bulldog, French Bulldog, Chinook, Bullmastiff, Shiba Inu, Shih Tzu.

Please note that I intentionally called them "breeds that don't bark so much", because (apart from Basenji) whether or not a dog barks is also a question of upbringing and training. You need to invest **a lot** of time during the first several months of owning a puppy to teach them how you'd like them to behave and to keep them from doing whatever they like when you're not around. You even should be around and supervising your puppy **nonstop** for at least the first 2 weeks of owning it.

If you just get a dog, even one that doesn't have the tendency to bark, and leave them to themselves most of the time, you'll be very disappointed in your dog-owning experience and your dog will be very disappointed in you.

Before deciding to adopt a dog, there are several more question you should keep in mind to choose the right dog for you. [This list](https://www.readersdigest.ca/home-garden/pets/cesar-millan-s-guide-choosing-dog/) is just one of them, there are several more [checklists](https://www.petfinder.com/pet-adoption/dog-adoption/dog-adoption-checklist/):

> What energy level should my dog have? Calm or energetic? Can I support an insecure dog or keep a workaholic happy?
>
> Do I want a purebred or a mutt? The purer the blood line the more intense are the characteristics of the breed. Most people experience a mutt as more mellow.
>
> Do I know enough to really choose the right dog for me? Do I know the alternatives? Do I know the characteristics of the breed I chose?
>
> Can I provide the right environment, the proper amount of time, and the appropriate stimulation to fulfill those inborn breed-related needs? Do my social obligations (like work, family, membership in any organization) prevent me from caring for my dog?
>
> Do I have a plan for my dog during vacations and/or work travel?
>
> Do I have a stable income to support a dog? In addition to dog food, you also need money for regular veterinary care, emergency veterinary care as result of an accident or illness, licensing or taxes (depending on where you live), regular grooming (depending on the breed), training classes, and many more.

Answer (score 2):

Labradors and retrievers are not really barking dogs. Keep in mind no matter what breed you get, they all have the instinct to bark. Some more than others, it just depends on their personality. My boxer doesn’t bark much. My English bulldog does as a guard dog and my boxer bulldog mix doesn’t bark much at all.

Answer (score 2):

I have a King Charles Cavalier, and he does not let out a peep! They are very easy to train, easy to groom (if you cut them short), and keep that little puppy look through adulthood (just grow bigger.) He is a very handsome man but is not generally a playful dog.